# Can enterprise keyword terms be isolated and hyperlinked?

Tags: managed-metadata, hyperlink, enterprise-keywords

I'm aiming to create a keyword column for a document library. The individual keywords should be hyperlinked search the site onClick.

I can't think of another way, so I'm attempting to employ the enterprise keyword column.

Is there a possible way to isolate the individual values of a keyword set and add  tags to them using a calculated column?

Comment: Are you on 2010 or 2013/Online?

Comment: I'm working on SP Online

I noticed the Keyword column can be filtered by individual items... so I figured that this might be possible.

Comment: So you want the keyword links in the View? Is CSR/JSlink an option?